# nginx vhost config

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

This is my config file for nginx to allow it to respond only to domain1.com, and not domain2.com

```
server {
    server_name  .domain1.com;
    root /var/www/;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

However this is still listening on domain2.com. What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, at least not this way. If the server receives a request with a `Host` header for a domain that is configured in no `server_name` statement, it will fall back to a default server, even if the `server_name` does not match.

See the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) for more info on the fallback order.

Answer (score 0):

Yep SvenW is correct, you need to set up a `default` vhost, possibly just set it to return a 404 if that's desired behaviour, or some sort of holding page.